# Programmatically scroll UIScrollView from left to right an reverse

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, reverse, right-to-left

I tried to automatic scroll from left to right but I have not succeeded yet.
I'm evaluating the following expresion to change direction (adding or substracting pixels) but when scroll arrives to final it is blocked...

```
(xContentSize - xOffset) >= CGRectGetWidth(_scroll.bounds)
```

or

```
(xContentSize - xOffset) > CGRectGetWidth(_scroll.bounds)
```

Any idea?

Comment: what do u want to refer "it blocked" ?

Comment: sovannarith,
The scroll is moved to right, but when it reaches to final, move to left and move to right indefinitely (it's blocked)

Comment: Could u show me your calculation of scrollview?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
float w = scrollView.frame.size.width;
float h = scrollView.frame.size.height;
float newPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x+w; 
CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, w, h);

[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];
```

manually set your desired position

Comment: where i need to write this. i mean in which scroll view delegate method. i wrote in scrollviewdidscroll but not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution.

With a NSTimer every 4.0 seconds

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                     animations:^{

                         if (_direction == 0) {
                             _scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake((_scroll.contentSize.width - CGRectGetWidth(_scroll.frame)), 0.0);
                         }else{
                             _scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
                         }

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         _direction = !_direction;
                     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** - scrolls 70px right and then back left (used to hint to users that there is pagination on a `UIScrollView`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction, .autoreverse], animations: {
  self.scrollView.contentOffset.x += 70
}) { [unowned self] _ in
  self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
}
```